# jquery custom plugin- manipulate after initialization

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am having trouble finding out how to manipulate a custom function I have written after binding it to an element. E.g. I have a function

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function(opts) {
    this.someFunction = function() { };

    $(this).keypress(function() {
        // do something
        someFunction();
    });
};

$('#some-element').myPlugin({ someOption: 'option'});
```

What I would like to do is set the optional function (someFunction) after the plugin has been set. So something along the lines of

```
$('#some-element').myPlugin("someFunction", function() { 
    // do something
});
```

I know I will need more parameters in myPlugin, and check whether it is the initial call (with opts) or something is being changed after initialization. But not quite sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the **[Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)** page of jQuery docs.

Can use this plugin development pattern (see ***Plugin Methods*** section):

```
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) { 
      // THIS 
    },
    show : function( ) {
      // IS
    },
    hide : function( ) { 
      // GOOD
    },
    update : function( content ) { 
      // !!! 
    }
  };

  $.fn.tooltip = function( method ) {

    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the jqueryui widget factory ? This has support for changing options after creation, as well as custom methods and events.

http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory